# Display and update data from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

So here is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to take information that has been entered on MySQL database and display it in an php file. With my code I've included below I am able to view the data for one user I login with, but once I logout and login with a different user the old users information is still displayed there is no update for the new users information. I also have made sure to end the session by creating a logout button which I have also included below.

```
<?php
 session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, username, passcode, email, Address, City, Country, Zip, FirstName, LastName, About FROM admin WHERE ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

?>
```

Snippet of my HTML

```
<html>

div class="form-group">

   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>">

                                            </div>


<html>
```

Logout php code

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: add WHERE condition in SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

change your sql query to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, passcode, email, Address, City, Country, Zip, FirstName, LastName, About FROM admin WHERE username = <variable_having_user_name_value>";
```

In case of other identifier than username (like email or id):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, passcode, email, Address, City, Country, Zip, FirstName, LastName, About FROM admin WHERE < identifier > = <variable_having_identifier_value>";
```

Comment: I tried changing my sql query and I didnt get anything. Does it have something do do with my code in html getting that to show the username.

Comment: how do you get to know, that which user is logged in ?

Comment: I go by username and password to log users in.

Comment: I'm trying to show all the info though such as address, city, etc.

Comment: where do you store the username of logged in user . session ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120461/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-user2921081).

Comment: Damn thats probably what I'm missing. Do I need to create a separate SQL table to store the user's current _SESSION ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, passcode, email, Address, City, Country, Zip, FirstName, LastName, About FROM admin WHERE ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

There is no WHERE data in your SQL. So I guess MySQL give you always the same user.

You need to provide a condition like :

```
// Get your user's profile data (from session for exemple)
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$passcode = your_cypher_function($_SESSION['passcode']);
// Then complete your query
$sql = "SELECT id, username, passcode, email, Address, City, Country, Zip, FirstName, LastName, About FROM admin WHERE email = $email AND passcode = $passcode";
```

Don't forget to protect your data from SQL injection. I gave you an easy exemple for quick testing.

Comment: I tried your solution and my php file is no longer loading in the browser. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: I made some edit, try again. How do you get the email of your logged-in user ? You will need these data to complete properly your SQL. Add this to display all PHP errors :
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Currently I don't have a registration page setup, but I have a email, username, pass, etc in the database on the table. The table is FROM admin.